# Normalizing data in Redshift

Tags: normalization, amazon-redshift

I've recently started using Redshift for housing millions of data points with a schema that looks like the following:

```
create table metrics (
  name varchar(100),
  value decimal(18,4),
  time timestamp
) sortkey (name, timestamp);
```

(The real schema is a bit more complex, but this will satisfy for my question)

I'm wondering if it makes sense to normalize my metric name (currently varchar(100)) by mapping it to an integer and only storing only the integer. (e.g. {id: 1, name: metric1}). The cardinality for `name` is ~100. By adding a mapping, it would make the application logic quite a bit more complex since it has many streams of input. Also, querying it ahead of time would require reverse mapping.

In a traditional sql database, this would be an obvious YES, but I'm not certain how Redshift handles this as it's a columnar data store. I think it would be nice to have in general, but I would assume that Redshift would/could do some similar mapping underneath the hood since certain columns in any table have lower cardinality than others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Redshift makes excellent use of compression and will store very few duplicates of your name field.

However you do need to ensure that you are making good use of Redshift's compression options. This section in the docs should tell you all you need to know: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html

TL;DR: Run ANALYZE COMPRESSION on your table to see what compression Redshift recommends, create a new table using those encodings, and insert your data into that table.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to continue to use the varchar data type, as you have here, but apply the "bytedict" compression type. Internally, this is the same as creating a lookup table, but it could actually be faster, since Redshift natively understands a manages it's own table and maps from int->string internally during column decoding.

Here is the bytedict doc reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Byte_dictionary_encoding.html

Another option that could give you good performance/storage savings for your use cases is runlength:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Runlength_encoding.html